# Wireshark dissect information but not display in the dissect

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

This may have been explained elsewhere, but not finding it. I have to work within the confines of wireshark 2.4.x.

So I defined some values for data as so.

```
        { &hf_td_timestamp,
            { "Timestamp", "td.timestamp",
                FT_ABSOLUTE_TIME, ABSOLUTE_TIME_LOCAL, NULL, 0x0, NULL, HFILL
            } },
        { &hf_td_timestamp_sec,
            { "Timestamp Seconds", "td.timestamp.sec",
                FT_UINT64, BASE_DEC, NULL, 0x0, NULL, HFILL
            } },
        { &hf_td_timestamp_nsec,
            { "Timestamp nSeconds", "td.timestamp.nsec",
                FT_UINT32, BASE_DEC, NULL, 0x0, NULL, HFILL
            } },
```

and the data for one of them gets stored and added to the dissect tree as so

```
        proto_tree_add_item(td_tree, hf_td_timestamp, tvb, offset, 8, ENC_TIME_TIMESPEC);
```

I only want to display the one line item and not all three. The information for the other two are of course derived from the same bytes. Ultimately I would like to have the other fields available for adding to the columns and not the detail dissect.

That is part 1. Once I can establish the storing of the information I will of course add the other two as a single line into the detail as seconds.nanoseconds. The values just need to be stored separately  so that the data can be parsed in an Excel csv file. Excel cannot handle the precision of the nanoseconds in decimal format, that is why they must be separate.

 Part 2: store some metadata that is calculated from known fields. Specifically the delta between these timestamps. Wireshark can give the delta of the recorded timestamp but not the timestamp within the payload. So basically store the delta between the payload timestamp with the same port information as the last packet from the same port. Once I can get past part 1 then I should be able to accomplish part 2.

So, is there a function that will parse the tvb and only store the value as opposed to store to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
proto_tree_add_item(td_tree, hf_td_timestamp, tvb, offset, 8, ENC_TIME_TIMESPEC);
proto_item * ti_sec = proto_tree_add_item(td_tree, hf_td_timestamp_sec, tvb, offset-4, 8, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
proto_item * ti_nsec = proto_tree_add_item(td_tree, hf_td_timestamp_nsec, tvb, offset+4, 8, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
PROTO_ITEM_SET_HIDDEN(ti_sec);
PROTO_ITEM_SET_HIDDEN(ti_nsec);
```

If the proto_tree_add_item() appears in the PROTO_ITEM_SET_HIDDEN() then the item will be displayed. PROTO_ITEM_SET_HIDDEN() works on previously declared items not currently created items.

As for part 2:
The metadata was created by generating a GHashTable for each new metadata item to hold the payload timestamps for each of the line numbers. (If there is a better way I would like to know. Like access the completed list if stored in wireshark as opposed to creating my own). Generate my timestamp deltas and convert the values into a tvb, then read the tvb back to store in the fields.

```
GHashTable * timestamp_map   = NULL;
GHashTable * timestamp_delta = NULL;
.
.
.
// Store the timestamp (key = linenum, value = timestamp)
timestamp_map = g_hash_table_new_full(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal, NULL, g_free);
// Store the list of line numbers from the associated client
timestamp_delta = g_hash_table_new_full(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal, NULL, g_list_free);
.
.
.
// find your deltas through your lookups
// convert to tvb and then to fields
// Create a new TVB to delta
tvbuff_t *tvbtmp = tvb_new_real_data(vals.buffer, 8, 8);
// Store in the field hf_tu_timestamp_delta
proto_tree_add_item(tree, hf_tu_timestamp_delta, tvbtmp, 0, 8, ENC_LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

NOTE: For very large captures the memory usage will be large (very large and expensive).